# Git merge not "merging"

Tags: git

So while trying to merge my branch with main, a conflict resulted in bash/alx which I'm supposed to resolve and successfully did. However when I used the checker, it says there's a problem with bash/school, and I tried to merge again but it says "already up to date". I then checked github and realized the change in the file "school" in the branch was not reflected in main. So how do i solve this when git keeps saying "up to date"?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to decide whether you did anything wrong. See [ask] and especially [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the merge conflict first, in order to merge the the branches.
Here is a link to [merge conflict documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line) that explains more and gives a step by step explanation of resolve conflict.